# Add link to my PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a PHP script that fetches the 'names' of some ID's on my DB. It then displays these 'names' on my index page as a user begins to search in the search bar. 
What I just can't seem to get working is the href link. I wish the 'names' that appear, hyperlink to their given page. 
Example: I search for The Beatles in the search bar 'The Beatles' is displayed on my search result and when I click 'The Beatles' link it takes me to www.mywebsite.com/'thebeatles'.html and it gives me thebealtes.html based on the 'names' that was fetched by my PHP script.

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "images";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

if(!empty($_GET['q'])){

    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE names like '%$q%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $name = $row['names'];

        echo '<a href=..........><div class="searchoutput">'.$name.'</a><br><div class="col-md-8"></div></div>';

    }
}
```

If someone could help me figure out what I put where I have put href=........ that would be great.

Comment: You have a table called `names` which contains a column also called `names` ...?

Comment: yes that is correct I followed a tutorial online and thats how it was set up. Once I have figured this all out I will create my proper DB with appropriate names.

Comment: Nice SQL injection exploit.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions how would one fix this exploit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($name));
echo '<a href="'.$link.'html"><div class="searchoutput">'.$name.'</a><br><div class="col-md-8"></div></div>';
```

Comment: You Sir have saved me some heart ache. Thank you. Worked like a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

Althought there are some good answers, they all have some mistakes that they overlooked.

1. href attribute needs quotes
2. When you open a div inside an a-tag, you need to close the div before closing the a-tag

   ```
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $password = "";
   $db = "images";

   $conn=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

   if(!empty($_GET['q'])){

   $q = $_GET['q'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE names like '%$q%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

       $name = $row['names'];
       $href = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($name));

       echo '<a href="'.$href.'.html"><div class="searchoutput">'.$name.'</div></a><br><div class="col-md-8"></div>';

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not to mention that the correct way to store this would be with one column with name, and one column for an "accessname"/href - so you're not dependant on using the content in name for the URL (which will come back to bite you). If you have one column for name, say "The Beatles" in a "name"-column, and one column for "href", say "thebeatles.html", you just pull both of them, and disperse them accordingly.

Comment: I agree that storing the href of each band in a seperate column would be a better structure and allows for easy handling of bandnames with special characters. To go even one step further, I would not make a html page for each band like 'thebeatles.html', but i would make a php page like 'detail.php?band=thebeatles' so you don't have to create a html page for each band.